# Use of Deviance Residuals for Leave-One-Out Cross Validation

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, residuals, deviance

I am a newbie to stats and having some difficulties understanding how to use deviance residuals for leave-one-out cross validation for a logistic regression model. The problem that I am trying to solve is unique in that the structure of the data is not particularly suitable for applying one of the procedure in software such as SAS. The problem is similar to this one (http://support.sas.com/kb/24/992.html) but assume that the data is based on opinions from 13 individuals. To validate the model, I wanted to leave data out for one individual at a time and generate deviance residuals for each case. I now have the deviance residuals for the full case with data from 13 individuals, and additional 13 cases where data from one individual is removed.

My questions are (1) how do I use these deviance residuals to perform the cross validation (leave-one-out) (2) what conclusions about my model can I be able to draw from the results? I would like to do this manually because of the nature of my data (calculated the residuals separately from each case).

Also, I am also open to other suggestions for accessing the predictive capability of such model.